# Multiple relations to one table in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

In my app a user can be friends with another user. So they have a many to many relationship between two tables. In this fashion: `Users > Friends < Users`

The tables look like:

```
Users:
id
username
password

Friends:
id
user_id_from
user_id_to
```

and I have set the Models up like so:

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'User';

    public $hasOne = 'Profile';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Post',
        'Answer',
    'Friend'
    );

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}

class Friend extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Friend';

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Sender' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id_from'
        ),
        'Recipient' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id_to'
        )
    );

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

However it doesn't seem to link them properly?

I use this code inside the User Model:

```
public function getFriends($username)
    {
        return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $username, 'Friend.status'=>1)

        ));
    }
```

and then when visiting a url like `/users/USERNAME/friends` it should list the friends for that person. The method that calls it is:

```
public function index( $username )
{   
    $friends = $this->User->getFriends($username);

    $this->set('friends', $this->paginate());
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Any updates please. As I'm really confused and want to get this fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a friend relationship, you should use HABTM instead of hasMany.

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'User';

    public $hasOne = 'Profile';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Post',
        'Answer',
    );

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
      'Friend' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'friends',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id_to',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id_from',
      )
    );

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Remove your current Friend model as it is not needed and will possibly confuse Cake.

Your `getFriends()` method will look like this:

```
public function getFriends($username) {
   return $this->find('all', array(
     'conditions' => array(
       'User.username' => $username, 
       'User.status'=>1
      ),
      'contain' => array(
        'Friend'
      )
   ));
}
```

Here, we search on the User model and include all that user's Friend records. Cake will automatically get the join table data and include the User data. `$this->User->getFriends('Jeremy');` will return data that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [username] => Jeremy
        )
    [Friend] => Array
        (
           [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [username] => Cameron
                )
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Mark
                )
           [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Bob
                )
        )
)
```

Each Friend key here is actually a User model result.

You can read more about HABTM here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

Comment: Gives me this error: Model "Friend" is not associated with model "Sender" `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Sender.username' in 'where clause'
SQL Query: SELECT `Friend`.`id`, `Friend`.`username`, `Friend`.`password`, `Friend`.`email`, `Friend`.`status`, `Friend`.`code`, `Friend`.`lastlogin` FROM `db52704_favorr`.`users` AS `Friend` WHERE `Sender`.`username` = 'cameron' AND `Friend`.`status` = 1`

Comment: I haven't changed anything in my Friend model (it's still as in my OP), so is their something I need to do there too that you haven't posted? Thanks

Comment: It's not joining the Sender model. Have you made sure that `Containable` is attached to the Friend model. Or, you can try `recursive` just to check it out.

Comment: The Friend model is EXACTLY as it is in my original post. So not sure if you can see if I'm missing anything?

Comment: I updated my answer. The `getFriends` function should search on the User model and contain the Friends it has.

Comment: Now I get: `Warning (512): Model "Friend" is not associated with model "Sender" [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]` and 
`Warning (512): Model "Friend" is not associated with model "Recipient" [CORE/Cake/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 339]`

Comment: What EXACTLY should I have in my friends model?

Comment: I think the problem is that the alias Friend (which is User) is getting confused with the model Friend (your HABTM join model). It might be best to start by using a conventional HABTM setup, remove your Friend model, the 'with' key, and let Cake auto-create it (unless you have anything special in the model, which it doesn't look like you do). Finding on a HABTM will bring in all the User data anyway, so you would only need `'contain' => 'Friend'`.

Comment: Could you do me a massive favour and post what should be in the User model and friend model including the getFriends method. As I'm just totally confused and don't understand how to fix this. Very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Alright I added more info. Like I said, remove the Friend model and the extra contain and you should be fine. It's a basic HABTM setup, except for the alias 'Friend' and the custom join table.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. According to the Cake Docs though you create models for the Join tables so I don't get why you have removed it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10025/discussion-between-jeremyharris-and-cameron)