# foreignKey in model based on condition in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I am struck with one issue related to `foreignKey` concept.
I have two table `users` & `user_relations`.

```
     users                                    user_relations

  id   username                           id   user_id   friend_id   status
  1     abc                                1       1         2      Accepted
  2     def                                2       2         3      Accepted
  3     ghi                                3       1         3      Accepted
```

here the `friend_id`  is the `foreign_key` and my `user_relations` model looks like

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Friend' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'friend_id'
    )
  );
```

My conditions will be like

```
'conditions' => array(
    "OR" => array(
        'UserRelation.user_id' => $iLoggedUserId,
        'UserRelation.friend_id' => $iLoggedUserId,
    ),
    'ViewerRelationship.status' => 'Accepted'
 )
```

Now when user `"1"` is logged in then he will get the info of users `"2"` & `"3"` based on `foreignKey` `friend_id`.

If user `"2"` gets logged in then, he is getting the info of users `"2"` & `"3"`. But here I need to get the info of users `"1"` & `"3"`. i.e., in one case it need to take the info based on the `user_id` not the `friend_id`

If I can keep the `foreignKey` in a condition I can get the result based on `user_id` or `friend_id`.

Any help please..!

Comment: Try changing your relationship to HABTM as shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112825/multiple-relations-to-one-table-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how it is effective for you.

But it will solve your problem.

```
$respone = $this->UserRelation->find('all', 
 array('conditions'=> array(
    'OR'=>array(
        'UserRelation.user_id' => $iLoggedUserId,
        'UserRelation.friend_id' => $iLoggedUserId
       )
    ), 
'fields' => array('UserRelation.*')
));
$reqFriendsId = array();
foreach($respone as $key => $val){
    if($val['UserRelation']['friend_id'] == $iLoggedUserId){
     array_push($reqFriendsId, $val['UserRelation']['user_id']);
    }else{
   array_push($reqFriendsId, $val['UserRelation']['friend_id']);
   }

}
```

//For logged in user 1

```
Array
(
[0] => 2
[1] => 3
)
```

//For logged in user 2

```
Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 3
)
```